# How to send traffic from one ubuntu machine to another

Tags: vps, traffic

I have two VPS from two different companies, they are both Ubuntu.

VPS-1 and VPS-2. And I have already set up a VPN server on the VPS-1. So that I can connect to the VPN from my phone.

What I want to do is to connect VPS-1 to VPS-2, so that the traffic of VPS-1 reaches the internet only by going to the VPS-2. Probably port forwarding is the solution, but I don't know how to do it, or if the traffic of the VPN will go to the internet via port forwarding. Any solution or help to this job is much aprreciated.

**Nutshell:**

The mobile phone connected to VPN (which is set up on VPS-1)

I browse the internet on my phone

The traffic goes to the VPS-2 via VPS1

And from VPS-2 to the internet.

Comment: If the goal of this is to hide the flow of traffic, two static hops is illogical. That sort of thing can be back-routed in about 15 seconds with typical script-kiddie packages 

Comment: No, it's not about hiding the flow of traffic. I'm working on a project and need to do such a thing :\